# Minecraft: Remove a mobs gravity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help removing the gravity of a mob. I am creating a puzzle where you teleport a chicken 1 block left/right/forward/backwards and I need to find a way for the chicken to jump.

I used a command to change the direction of the chicken to up but it dies when it touches the block on top of it.

Command:

```
/entitydata @e[score_gravity_min=1] {Motion:[0.0,1.0,0.0]}
```

[image: My chicken Henry]

[image: My commands (Purple=Allways active, Brown=Needs redstone)]

[image: R.I.P]

Comment: could you try naming the chicken? This should send a death message, like `Test123 suffocated to death`, which would tell us what the chicken is dieing from.

Comment: @ash4fun Death messages only work on players, not on mobs, even if renamed.

Comment: @nelson2tm I know they work on tamed dogs, and I assumed it would work for chickens, too.

Comment: @ash4fun No, only on tamed animals (such as dogs and cats).

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.9, `NoAI` no longer prevents gravity.

But as of 1.10, `NoGravity` has been extended to all entities. You can use this to prevent mobs from falling due to gravity:

```
/summon Chicken ~ ~1 ~ {NoGravity:1b}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NoAI:1` in your NBT tags. Notice that the chicken doesn't do anything. He doesn't even look at players nearby.

For example, your command with the NBT tag would be:

```
/entitydata @e[score_gravity_min=1] {Motion:[0.0,1.0,0.0],NoAI:1}
```

Comment: the chicken already has no ai

Comment: Could you try to make a video/screenshot of what you're doing? I totally have no idea what you mean by touching the block above it. It would make the question clearer.

Comment: `NoAI` no longer prevents gravity.

Comment: @Skylinerw Didn't know that. Last time experimenting in one of the snapshots when 1.9 wasn't out yet, it did prevent gravity.